# Transferring a Q-learning policy to larger instances

Tags: deep-rl, q-learning, dqn, transfer-learning

**How do I best transfer and fine-tune a Q-learning policy that was trained on small instances to large instances?**

*Some more details on the problem:*
I am currently trying to derive a decision policy for a dynamic vehicle dispatching problem.
In the problem, a decision point occurs whenever a customer requests delivery. Customers expect to be delivered within a fixed amount of time and the objective is to minimize the delay. The costs of each state are the delays realized in that state (i.e., the delay of the customers that were delivered between the last two states.

*Some details on the policy:*
I used a Q-learning policy (Dueling Deep Q Network) to estimate the discounted future delay of assigning an order to a vehicle. The policy was trained on a small-scale instance (5 vehicles ~100 customers) using epsilon-greedy exploration and a prioritized experience replay. I did not use temporal difference learning (as the cost of a decision are only revealed later in the process) but updated the policy after simulating the entire instance.

*My problem:*
As it is, the policy transfers well to instances of larger sizes (up to 100 vehicles and ~2000 customers) and I could do without fine-tuning. However, there certainly is room for the policy to improve. Unfortunately, when I try to fine-tune the initial model on the larger instance, the retrained model becomes worse over the training steps with regards to minimizing delay.
I suspect that large gradients play a role here as the initial q-values, trained on the small instance, are obviously way off for the large instances (due to the increase in customers).

**Is there a standard approach to deal with such a transfer problem or do you have any suggestions?**